# Disable other rule when a Rule is fired

Tags: drools

I have three rules **A**, **B** and **C**

If **either** A or B is  fired, C should not be fired

A and B can be fired **together**

How to construct this in drools *Decision Table*?

I tried to have both A and B in same agenda-group **and** same activation-group,

```
+--------+------------+--------------+------------------+----------+
|  Name  | auto-focus | agenda-group | activation-group | priority |
+--------+------------+--------------+------------------+----------+
| Rule_A | true       | Rule_Agenda  | Rule_Activation  |        3 |
| Rule_B | true       | Rule_Agenda  | Rule_Activation  |        2 |
| Rule_C |            |              | Rule_Activation  |        1 |
+--------+------------+--------------+------------------+----------+
```

That didn't work as activation-group overrides

Answer (score 0):

`If either A or B is fired` has business meaning to you, right. So you need to introduce event which represent this meaningful situation and insert it into knowledge base which should be taken into consideration by rule C. Technically you would need lower salience for rule C and you can use [logical insertions](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.43.1.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#inference-and-truth-maintenance_decision-engine) not to bother with this event lifecycle